# Организация двустороннего обмена данными в реальном времени меджу двумя БД

Tags: oracle, синхронизация, mysql

Привет всем! 
Поступил такой заказ, что нужно сделать синхронизацию баз данных интернет-магазина, построенного на базе Magento, который работает на БД MySQL, и ИС Предприятия, у которого все данные хранятся в БД Oracle.

Заказчик хочет, чтобы при регистрации на сайте, если пользователь не существует в ИС предприятия, чтобы он создавался там, Если пользователя завели в ИС предприятия, он должен создаваться автоматически в БД Magento. Причем, должно это происходить как можно быстрее, заказчик хочет, чтобы этот процесс происходил в течении не больше одной минуты. Процессов там много(Синхронизация товаров, услуг, бухгалтерия, и так далее). Собственно, все это нужно синхронизировать.

Первое, что пришло в очередь - это повешать скрипт в крон, который будет дергаться каждую минуту, но он сразу отпал, т.к. некоторые скрипты могут выполняться более минут, что неприемлемо. Можно конечно, проверять, не запущен ли скрипт перед каждым его запуском, но в таком случае мы получаем однопоточную очередь.

Отсюда пришла вторая мысль - использовать сервер задач, к примеру, gearman. Вопрос производительности решается созданием дополнительных воркеров, в итоге, лищняя работа не будет делаться(лишние запуски скриптов), таким образом можно организовать обмен данными почти в реальном времени.

Подскажите пожалуйста, на что еще стоит обратить внимание, может придложете свой способ, который считаете более лучшим?

Comment: >> на что еще стоит обратить внимание
особый случай - два пользователя одновременно регистрируются в двух разных базах (под словом одновременно понимается меньше минуты, так что бы в базы данные попали, а синхронизация ещё не началась). Нужно будет уметь разруливать такие конфликты.

Answer (score 2):

Зачем вы изобретаете велосипед? Вообще то нормальная СУБД всегда имеет свой встроенный механизм репликации/синхронизации данных между разными БД.

Oracle не исключение. Посмотрите например, в сторону [Oracle Golden Gate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/goldengate/overview/index.html). Подобных продуктов много - погуглите. На память приходят Tungsten, DBSync, PervaSync и проч. Не уверен, что они все подойдут - поищите дальше сами.

Gearman/cron и проч. это средства распределения задач на которые вы будете вешать какие-то самопальные скрипты - ИМХО это не работоспособно.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ответ. Структуры баз данных различаются друг от друга. Репликация как на это отреагирует?

Comment: если разные типы и структуры баз, то лучше наладить общение между приложениями в виде api.

Comment: @nolka - GoldenGate поддерживает маппинг полей - то есть можно задавать какое поле будет отображаться на какое поле, фильтровать и т.д. - можно задавать достаточно сложные правила маппинга - [примеры](http://www.juliandyke.com/Blog/?p=396) - другие продукты, уверен, также поддерживают подобные фичи. Это не тупая репликация :)

Comment: @Barmaley, я не думаю что стоит двум разным приложениям напрямую писать в одну и ту-же базу, опасносте.

Comment: @eicto, в чем опасность?

Comment: в том что при каком-нибудь изменении в "ИС предприятия" способ обращения к базе может измениться ну и прочие радости создания пользователей напрямую. тем более используя для этого репликацию

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то master в данной схеме Oracle и slave - MeSQL. А почему вам не использовать линк из оракла на базу mysql, и при добавлении (к примеру на триггерах) - обеспечить вызов процедуры/скрипта для добавления пользователя в MySQL? [How To Access MySQL from Oracle With ODBC and SQL](http://www.pythian.com/blog/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/)